# How to decide the right sample size in A/B testing

Tags: experiment-design, statistical-power, ab-test

I'm working on a price optimization problem where I want to change the price of a product and see if the revenue becomes higher.

So, I have 40 different stores in my experiments and I split them into 2 groups, test and control and change the price of the product of interest in test stores only and would like to compare the revenue with control stores after a while. How should I go about picking the minimum number of transactions, minimum number of days/weeks to run the experiment etc.

As there might be slight differences in my test and control stores, I'm thinking of using Difference in difference approach and compare the revenue lift in test post vs. pre and compare it with control, that is

test_lift = (revenue_test_post - revenue_test_pre)/revenue_test_pre

control_lift = (revenue_control_post - revenue_control_pre)/revenue_control_pre

and I compare test_lift and control_lift.

let's say if I run the experiment for 4 weeks, I consider the post period as 4 weeks and also consider the pre period as last 4 weeks right before the experiment starts.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before and the answer is it depends.  What is your desired improvement you are looking for in the test samples?  If the sales double or triple you will need far fewer samples than if you are only interested in a few percent difference.

Comment: I;m expecting a very small lift in sales, e.g. 1,2 or 3%.